# jquery [on] function display different result?

Tags: jquery

what happened?

`$('body').on('click',"div",function(){console.log($(this))})`  //prints div

`$('body').on('click',"div",()=>{console.log($(this))})` //prints window

I try

Comment: Nothing to do with `.on` or even jQuery. You're using different types of functions that work differently.

Comment: Another good read for ya: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: break my cognition. I am going study. thanks every one